# Problem with EWS functions having converted authentication to oAuth

Tags: oauth, exchangewebservices

I am converting some old code that was using basic authentication to use oAuth. The authentication seems to be working fine but then functions that were working are now failing

```
        Dim mySession As New ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion.Exchange2016)

        Dim cca = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder.Create(EWSClientId).WithClientSecret(EWSClientSecret).WithTenantId(EWSTenantId).Build
        Dim authResult = Await cca.AcquireTokenForClient(EWSScopes).ExecuteAsync()

        mySession.Credentials = New OAuthCredentials(authResult.AccessToken)

        mySession.TraceListener = New TraceListener
        mySession.TraceFlags = TraceFlags.All
        mySession.TraceEnabled = True

        mySession.ImpersonatedUserId = New ImpersonatedUserId(ConnectingIdType.SmtpAddress, EmailAddressToScan)

        Try
            mySession.AutodiscoverUrl(EmailAddressToScan, AddressOf RedirectionCallback)
        Catch ex As Exception
            mySession.Url = New Uri(EWSServerName)
        End Try

        Dim rootfolder As Folder = Folder.Bind(mySession, WellKnownFolderName.MsgFolderRoot)
```

EWSScopes is https://outlook.office365.com/.default

EWSServerName is https://outlook.office365.com/ews/exchange.asmx

EmailAddressToScan is cm.workflow@sydney.edu.au

EWSClientId, EWSClientSecret and EWSTenantId contain the appropriate values

Authentication appears to work and I am seeing the token in the heading calls but the AutodiscoverUrl and Folder calls both fail. Other than adding the impersonation line the code worked with basic authentication.

For AutodiscoverUrl I get an error of "**The Autodiscover service couldn't be located**".

I have headers of:

```
<Trace Tag="AutodiscoverRequestHttpHeaders" Tid="12" Time="2022-09-20 01:54:40Z">
POST /autodiscover/autodiscover.svc HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
Accept: text/xml
User-Agent: ExchangeServicesClient/2.2.1.0
Authorization: Bearer eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJub25jZSI6ImdXQ2g4b0hiQXRmdUM2bVJUSkh2YWZhdmIwUVRsQTFxbURyeHlaQmpvZ3ciLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsIng1dCI6IjJaUXBKM1VwYmpBWVhZR2FYRUpsOGxWMFRPSSIsImtpZCI6IjJaUXBKM1VwYmpBWVhZR2FYRUpsOGxWMFRPSSJ9.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.kl-Hl8HJ19rgeZGGXYaW8FrOOyt9xSuX2GXXERN9TFVkG0wttJacXYDC5fvGnWmQg86ACAPBReiT9zvX7xguNKPJdelhpwACMO4os3mB3GsjVmqqk3mAIXHZ0_75U77ReUEmvH_u1scppUlXnt-aM_yCLALp2NIkyqpE8BV3LTMNwoRsls5ya7M7i0HsIOBoezLScCAFDJy8WEfBi_yJjwOUEQdDLi0NEHs3qU9KA3t9KIDJTt4ZxlieO92mSr5OWJlgLGwFzqlxq-r5-rm1Z1fjDWJAq9IYvkqnB-BP-lpds1HX1LnuAS5_TtPRDAALJfskkwp5KdPj0uq9CKvT6g


</Trace>
```

The body is:

```
<Trace Tag="AutodiscoverRequest" Tid="12" Time="2022-09-20 01:54:40Z" Version="2.2.1.0">
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <soap:Envelope xmlns:a="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/2010/Autodiscover" xmlns:wsa="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <soap:Header>
      <a:RequestedServerVersion>Exchange2013_SP1</a:RequestedServerVersion>
      <wsa:Action>http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/2010/Autodiscover/Autodiscover/GetUserSettings</wsa:Action>
      <wsa:To>https://email.sydney.edu.au/autodiscover/autodiscover.svc</wsa:To>
    </soap:Header>
    <soap:Body>
      <a:GetUserSettingsRequestMessage xmlns:a="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/2010/Autodiscover">
        <a:Request>
          <a:Users>
            <a:User>
              <a:Mailbox>cm.workflow@sydney.edu.au</a:Mailbox>
            </a:User>
          </a:Users>
          <a:RequestedSettings>
            <a:Setting>InternalEwsUrl</a:Setting>
            <a:Setting>ExternalEwsUrl</a:Setting>
          </a:RequestedSettings>
        </a:Request>
      </a:GetUserSettingsRequestMessage>
    </soap:Body>
  </soap:Envelope>
</Trace>
```

and the response is

```
<Trace Tag="AutodiscoverResponse" Tid="12" Time="2022-09-20 01:54:41Z">
Autodiscover service call failed with error 'The request failed. The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized.'. Will try legacy service
</Trace>

<Trace Tag="AutodiscoverResponse" Tid="12" Time="2022-09-20 01:54:41Z">
Autodiscover service returned redirection URL 'https://www.sydney.edu.au/autodiscover/autodiscover.xml'.
</Trace>

<Trace Tag="AutodiscoverResponse" Tid="12" Time="2022-09-20 01:54:41Z">
Autodiscover service returned redirection URL 'https://email.sydney.edu.au/autodiscover/autodiscover.xml'.
</Trace>
```

For the Folder call I get an error of "**The token contains not enough scope to make this call**".

I have headers of

```
<Trace Tag="EwsRequestHttpHeaders" Tid="12" Time="2022-09-20 01:55:21Z">
POST /ews/exchange.asmx HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
Accept: text/xml
User-Agent: ExchangeServicesClient/2.2.1.0
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
Authorization: Bearer eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJub25jZSI6ImdXQ2g4b0hiQXRmdUM2bVJUSkh2YWZhdmIwUVRsQTFxbURyeHlaQmpvZ3ciLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsIng1dCI6IjJaUXBKM1VwYmpBWVhZR2FYRUpsOGxWMFRPSSIsImtpZCI6IjJaUXBKM1VwYmpBWVhZR2FYRUpsOGxWMFRPSSJ9.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.kl-Hl8HJ19rgeZGGXYaW8FrOOyt9xSuX2GXXERN9TFVkG0wttJacXYDC5fvGnWmQg86ACAPBReiT9zvX7xguNKPJdelhpwACMO4os3mB3GsjVmqqk3mAIXHZ0_75U77ReUEmvH_u1scppUlXnt-aM_yCLALp2NIkyqpE8BV3LTMNwoRsls5ya7M7i0HsIOBoezLScCAFDJy8WEfBi_yJjwOUEQdDLi0NEHs3qU9KA3t9KIDJTt4ZxlieO92mSr5OWJlgLGwFzqlxq-r5-rm1Z1fjDWJAq9IYvkqnB-BP-lpds1HX1LnuAS5_TtPRDAALJfskkwp5KdPj0uq9CKvT6g


</Trace>
```

A body of:

```
<Trace Tag="EwsRequest" Tid="12" Time="2022-09-20 01:55:21Z" Version="2.2.1.0">
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/messages" xmlns:t="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <soap:Header>
      <t:RequestServerVersion Version="Exchange2013_SP1" />
      <t:ExchangeImpersonation>
        <t:ConnectingSID>
          <t:SmtpAddress>cm.workflow@sydney.edu.au</t:SmtpAddress>
        </t:ConnectingSID>
      </t:ExchangeImpersonation>
    </soap:Header>
    <soap:Body>
      <m:GetFolder>
        <m:FolderShape>
          <t:BaseShape>AllProperties</t:BaseShape>
        </m:FolderShape>
        <m:FolderIds>
          <t:DistinguishedFolderId Id="msgfolderroot" />
        </m:FolderIds>
      </m:GetFolder>
    </soap:Body>
  </soap:Envelope>
</Trace>
```

And the response header is:

```
<Trace Tag="EwsResponseHttpHeaders" Tid="12" Time="2022-09-20 01:55:21Z">
HTTP/1.1 403 
request-id: 616ab081-7eca-3eaa-830c-464f02f3b2b1
Alt-Svc: h3=":443",h3-29=":443"
X-CalculatedBETarget: SY4PR01MB6346.ausprd01.PROD.OUTLOOK.COM
X-BackEndHttpStatus: 403
X-RUM-Validated: 1
x-ms-appId: 15ab54fc-8996-4ddc-8f61-7ef1a3194713
Restrict-Access-Confirm: 1
x-ms-diagnostics: 2000008;reason="The token contains not enough scope to make this call.";error_category="invalid_grant"
X-BeSku: WCS6
X-DiagInfo: SY4PR01MB6346
X-BEServer: SY4PR01MB6346
X-Proxy-RoutingCorrectness: 1
X-Proxy-BackendServerStatus: 403
X-FirstHopCafeEFZ: SYD
X-FEProxyInfo: SYBPR01CA0157.AUSPRD01.PROD.OUTLOOK.COM
X-FEEFZInfo: SYD
X-FEServer: SYBPR01CA0157
Content-Length: 0
Cache-Control: private
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
Date: Tue, 20 Sep 2022 01:55:20 GMT
Set-Cookie: exchangecookie=ee75b36c72834812b81e7c7cb5ab2a23; expires=Wed, 20-Sep-2023 01:55:21 GMT; path=/; secure; HttpOnly
Server: Microsoft-IIS/10.0
WWW-Authenticate: Bearer client_id="00000002-0000-0ff1-ce00-000000000000", trusted_issuers="00000001-0000-0000-c000-000000000000@*", token_types="app_asserted_user_v1 service_asserted_app_v1", error="invalid_token"
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET


</Trace>
```

Can anyone provide me some direction as to what I am doing wrong or have not configured correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use the Tokens from the client credentials flow with Autodiscoverv1 (In EWS it requires impersonation which isn't supported in Autodiscover), if all your users are in the cloud then its redundant call that can be removed and you can just use the static well-known office365 ews endpoint "https://outlook.office365.com/ews/exchange.asmx" uri, if you have Hybrid mailboxes and you need to detect if a mailbox is onPrem or in the Cloud I would suggest you use Autodiscoverv2 which is un-authenticated.

With the token that your trying to use in GetFolder it doesn't contain the scope/roles for EWS eg if take you token and decode it with jwt.io it doesn't contain any roles. An example of what you should see is

[image]

This most likely means you didn't either add the application permission to the application registration (eg a common mistake it to add the delegate one)"full_access_as_app" or it hasn't been consented to in the tenant.